# Shared connection : User is not a valid entity or mapped super class

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I had 5 minutes ago a full setup with FOS userBundle which was working. Then i decided to use multiple / shared db connections. And now i've got :

```
MyNamespace\UserBundle\Entity\User is not a valid entity or mapped super class.
```

Here's the setting.

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   %database_driver%
                host:     %database_host%
                port:     %database_port%
                dbname:   %database_name%
                user:     %database_user%
                password: %database_password%
                charset:  UTF8
            shared:
                driver:   %database_shared_driver%
                host:     %database_shared_host%
                port:     %database_shared_port%
                dbname:   %database_shared_name%
                user:     %database_shared_user%
                password: %database_shared_password%
                charset:  UTF8

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
              connection: default
              mappings:
                MyNonSharedBundle: ~
            shared:
              connection: shared
              mappings:
                MyUserBundle: ~
                FOSUserBundle: ~
```

PS: If i Move `MyUserBundle` and `FosUserBundle` under the `default connection`, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means something is trying to work with your entity through default entity manager. Did you  configure FOSUserBundle?

```
fos_user:
    model_manager_name: "shared"
```

Comment: Thanks it was that. Is this only related to FOSUserBundle or I must cfg each bundle i put under shared ?

Comment: But it continues to crash when doctrine:schema:create with the same error message :/

Comment: It shouldn't... Will it do it with `--em=shared` parameter for  doctrine:schema:create?

Comment: when i do that it tells me : MyUserBundle is not a valid entity. and when doing with --em:default, it tells me the opposit (MyUserBundle and FOSUserBundle)....

Comment: @Tristan weird, if you set `--em=shared` it should generate the schema for MyUserBundle and FOSUserBundle. Where that error come from?

Comment: Take a look yourself : http://pastie.org/private/xeehuguwzrw1pgebmiv5a is it a bug in 2.1 ? should i open a ticket ? or is it only impacting me ?

Comment: Oh god, i know what's happening, in the User class i have relations to Offer, and vice-versa. So when he tries to create the schema, he looks for "Offer" ? which is not existing yet. How to bypass that ? Or maybe i'm wrong?

Comment: I think you're right. Try to remove relations. Doctrine can't do join with two tables in different databases, you can't bypass it.

Comment: That sucks. Thanks for your help meze.